# SQL queries performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Which one of these SQL queries will perform better? Assume that the give the same results:

```
SELECT mov_title, mov_year, mov_dt_rel, act_fname, act_lname, dir_fname, dir_lname
FROM movie 
JOIN movie_cast 
ON movie.mov_id = movie_cast.mov_id
JOIN actor
ON actor.act_id = movie_cast.act_id
JOIN movie_direction
ON movie.mov_id = movie_direction.mov_id
JOIN director
ON director.dir_id = movie_direction.dir_id
WHERE movie.mov_id IN (SELECT mov_id 
FROM rating WHERE rev_id IN (SELECT rev_id
FROM reviewer
WHERE rev_name IS NULL));

SELECT mov_title, mov_year, mov_dt_rel, dir_fname, dir_lname, 
       act_fname, act_lname
       FROM movie a, movie_direction b, director c, 
                rating d, reviewer e, actor f, movie_cast g
       WHERE a.mov_id=b.mov_id
AND  b.dir_id=c.dir_id 
 AND a.mov_id=d.mov_id 
  AND  d.rev_id=e.rev_id 
   AND  a.mov_id=g.mov_id 
    AND g.act_id=f.act_id 
     AND e.rev_name IS NULL;
```

In general what are the query performance considerations, other than number of rows returned.

Comment: You could just try running them both on your data...

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN {query}` on both and see if they are the same too. Why isn't the first question doing a JOIN on `rating` and/or `reviewer`. The right indexes will help this query significantly. ref: https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization  and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

`IN (SELECT ...)` *may* be a performance killer.  It is *usually* better to avoid that construct.

The first formulation (with "JOIN..ON") is the "right" way to do SQL this century.  The second ("comma-join") is old fashioned; don't use it.  (This is not a *performance* difference, just a style diff.)